# Angular Validator URL using rfc2396 and custom ValidatorFn

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, validation, angular8

I noticed that `type="url"` gets ignored in Angular 8 when using Reactive Form. I am trying to validate the URL/URI using RFC2396 since the form gets sent to a .NET Core API.

I think .NET Core uses [Uri.CheckSchemaName with RFC2396](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.checkschemename?view=netcore-2.2#remarks) and I wanted to do the same validation in Angular and avoid having two different RegEx to validate the URL/URI.

[RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#appendix-B)

Here is my Custom Angular Validator

```js
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function urlValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
        const uriRegEx = RegExp('^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?', 'g');
        const result = uriRegEx.test(control.value);

        if (!result) {
            return { 'invalid-url': true };
        }

        return null;
    };
}
```

The `result` is always `true` no matter what `control.value` is.

Disclaimer: Did my best looking for an answer and avoid the infamous duplicated.

[Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h75v1l)

Comment: Your result is true because the regex can match an empty string at any location in the input text. Add  `$` at the end and remove `g` flag.

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew I did as you said and still get the result to be true. I added a Stackblitz link to see it in action